# SQL - Select non-null value based on the most recent date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using a SQL query to get the most recent non-null values except if all null
This is based on the 'id' column.

Consider this table:

```
create table calc
(
     id int, 
     tms date,
     col1 int, 
     col2 int, 
     col3 int
);

insert into calc 
values (1, '1/1/2000', 100, 333, null),
       (1, '3/3/2000', null, 222, null),
       (1, '2/2/2000', 300, 111, null);
```

Expected output:

```
1,'3/3/2000',300,222,null
```

Below is the query I ran but it only returns row with max date

```
select 
    c.id, max_dt, col1, col2, col3
from 
    calc c
inner join 
    (select id, max(tms) as max_Dt
     from calc
     group by id) a on a.id = c.id and a.max_dt = tms;
```

Actual output:

```
1,'3/3/2000',null,222,null
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired solution?

Comment: Please tag properly. Which DBMS Oracle or SQL-Server ..?

Comment: Looks like a job for APPLY.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made some modifications of your original query. As written by you, it's normal to have null in the 3rd position in your output shown above, it looks like :

```
select * from calc where id =1 and tms = '3/3/2000');
```

Can yo try this :

```
select c.id, nvl(tms,max_dt) tms, nvl(col1,mcol1) col1, nvl(col2,mcol2) col2, 
nvl(col3,mcol3) col3
from 
calc c
inner join 
(select id, max(tms) max_Dt, max(col1) mcol1, max(col2) mcol2, max(col3) mcol3 
 from calc
 group by id) a on a.id = c.id and a.max_dt = tms;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: You are welcome ;) Happy for you that you resolved your problem.

Comment: This solution is horribly slow if you are to preform operations on 10 columns on 40,000 rows..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic SQL way to do it ("the hard way"). Probably this could be improved if you provide the DBMS you're using.

```
select id,
    max(tms) as max_dt,
    (select col1 
        from calc c1 
        where c1.id = c.id and c1.tms = 
        (select max(tms) from calc where id = c1.id and col1 is not null) ) max_col1,
    (select col2 
        from calc c2 
        where c2.id = c.id and c2.tms = 
        (select max(tms) from calc where id = c2.id and col2 is not null) ) max_col2,
    (select col3 
        from calc c3 
        where c3.id = c.id and c3.tms = 
        (select max(tms) from calc where id = c3.id and col3 is not null) ) max_col3
from calc c
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT t11.id,
           t14.tms,
           t11.col1,
           t12.col2,
           t13.col3
    FROM
      (SELECT calc.id,
              col1
       FROM calc
       INNER JOIN
         (SELECT id,
                 max(tms) tms
          FROM calc
          WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY id)AS t1 ON t1.id = calc.id
       AND t1.tms = calc.tms) AS t11
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT calc.id,
              col2
       FROM calc
       INNER JOIN
         (SELECT id,
                 max(tms) tms
          FROM calc
          WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY id)AS t2 ON t2.id = calc.id
       AND t2.tms = calc.tms) AS t12 ON t11.id = t12.id
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT calc.id,
              col3
       FROM calc
       INNER JOIN
         (SELECT id,
                 max(tms) tms
          FROM calc
          WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY id)AS t3 ON t3.id = calc.id
       AND t3.tms = calc.tms) AS t13 ON t11.id = t13.id
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT id,
              max(tms) tms
       FROM calc
       GROUP BY id)AS t14 ON t11.id = t14.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without subqueries at all, using the `keep` keyword:

```
select id, max(tms),
       max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 2 end), tms desc) as col1,
       max(col2) keep (dense_rank first order by (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 2 end), tms desc) as col2,
       max(col3) keep (dense_rank first order by (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 2 end), tms desc) as col3
from calc
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f05a4e47df921d3f6bc4deedbe7a08a2) is a db<>fiddle.